# hyphen in API params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, parameters

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644546/saving-the-information-emailed-and-processed-via-mailgun-into-my-app) specifically mentions using the params `[:body-plain]`. However, Rails throws this error: `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'plain' for #<IncomingMailsController:0x0000000913f278>):`

How can I access params that have a hyphen in? I can't change the params as they're posted from a third party API ([Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to access them like this:

```
params[:'body-plain']
```

Or even just like this:

```
params["body-plain"]
```

You have to escape your `symbol` name if it contains special characters.

Comment: Thanks - should have realised!

Comment: How would you use params like these to create a record if the record expects underscored params?

Comment: You can't, you'd have to turn from one to the other.